How to Keep TextField Cursor Visible Above Keyboard When Typing Long Text?
I'm working on a Jetpack Compose project where I need a full-screen TextField. However, I'm running into an issue where the cursor hides behind the keyboard when the user types long text. I've already tried using Modifier.imePadding() and Modifier.fillMaxSize() to ensure the text field adjusts for the keyboard, but the issue persists.

I’ve applied Modifier.fillMaxSize() to make the TextField take up the entire screen.
I’ve added Modifier.imePadding() to handle padding when the keyboard appears.

Despite these attempts, the cursor still hides behind the keyboard when typing long text. I want the text field to remain visible and scrollable, so that the cursor is always in view when the keyboard is open.

One fast solution is to change the text Field height to be right above the keyboard when it's showing, and change it back to full screen when the keyboard disappears.

This question is similar to: Software keyboard overlaps content of jetpack compose view. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
